# How can I select every nth date in Snowflake?

Tags: sql, date, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, modulo

Say I have a table in Snowflake with fields `delivery_date`, formatted as a DATETIME, and `daily_volume` formatted as an INT. `Daily_volume` follows a pattern that repeats every 10 days.

How would I query this table to compare today's `daily_volume`, compared to the historical average of that same point in the 10 day cycle?

My first instinct would be to do something like:

```
WHERE MOD(current_date(),10) = MOD(delivery_date,10)
```

then take the average, but Snowflake doesn't seem to have any easy way to convert a DATETIME to an INT so that I can make the MOD function work.

ChatGPT suggested something along the lines of

```
WHERE MOD(DATEDIFF('days', '1970-01-01'::DATE, current_date), 10) 
   = MOD(DATEDIFF('days', '1970-01-01'::DATE, delivery_date), 10)
```

which works, I guess, but I'm guessing there's a better way?

Answer (score 1):

[TIME_SLICE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/time_slice):

> Calculates the beginning or end of a “slice” of time, where the length of the slice is a multiple of a standard unit of time (minute, hour, day, etc.).
>
> This function can be used to calculate the start and end times of fixed-width “buckets” into which data can be categorized.

```
SELECT 
    TIME_SLICE(delivery_date, 10, 'DAY', 'START') AS START_OF_SLICE
   ,TIME_SLICE(delivery_date, 10, 'DAY', 'END') AS END_OF_SLICE
FROM tab
```

---

EDIT:

`date - '1970-01-01'::DATE` - returns number of days

```
WHERE MOD(current_date() - '1970-01-01'::DATE,10) 
    = MOD(delivery_date - '1970-01-01'::DATE,10)
```

Comment: I don't think this will get me there by itself... This will tell me which 10 day segment a day is in, but not where in the cycle the day falls. I'd need to do some date subtraction in addition to this to get what I'm looking for, right?